# regex for comma separated numbers in brackets

Tags: regex, bash

I am searching for regex which could be used for testing number or comma separated numbers in {} brackets

```
34
{567}
{12,13,14,30,101,23}
```

I have following regex which works find for first two examples but not no third one

```
echo "{2424242,243,243,2,2,11}"|grep -E '^([1-9][0-9]*|\{[1-9][0-9]*\}|\{([1-9][0-9]*,)[1-9][0-9]*\})$'
```

what is wrong with: `\{([1-9][0-9]*,)[1-9][0-9]*\}`?

Comment: The wrong thing is that you don't look for repeated comma separated digits and you allow a single comma and restrict numbers to start with `1`. I think you have to do this  `^([0-9]+|{[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*})$`

Comment: If a solution fits your problem you should consider accepting it by clicking on check mark beside it. As I see your questions you never did this before. It's good to close your questions as solved in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is missing the last case when we don't have the comma at the end. And it doesn't account for repetition. So adding `?` after the comma and `+` after the inner capturing group `([1-9][0-9]*,)+` solves the problem. This one matches the last line too:

```
^([1-9][0-9]*|\{[1-9][0-9]*\}|\{([1-9][0-9]*,?)+[1-9][0-9]*\})$
```

You can see the [live version here](https://regex101.com/r/SS3E7G/1)
By the way it could be written in shorter way but i will leave it to you preference.

Comment: thank you, I have already done such regex thx to revo - it seems to do the job as well `^([1-9][0-9]*|\{[1-9][0-9]*(,[1-9][0-9]*)*\}|\{[1-9][0-9]*\})$` btw. which shorter way did you mean? I need it for bash string test `[[ "${1}" =~ hereregex ]] || ...`

Comment: For one you can use \d instead of [0-9] second you can use  [subroutine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) for repeating patter `[1-9][0-9]*` it is supported from PCRE 4.0 but it doesn't make much difference so i left it out for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong thing is that you don't look for repeated comma separated digits, you allow a single comma and restrict numbers to start with 1 through 9 (skip this if it is on purpose). I think you have to do this:

```
^([0-9]+|{[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*})$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=(34)
a+=( '{567}' )
a+=( '{12,13,14,30,101,23}' )

a+=( '{12,13,14,30,101,23' )
a+=( '12,13,14,30,101,23}' )
a+=( '12,13,14,30,101,23' )

regex='^([1-9][0-9]*|\{[1-9][0-9]*(,[1-9][0-9]*)*\})$'

for test in ${a[@]}; do
    grep -E "$regex" <<< "$test"
done

for test in ${a[@]}; do
    [[ $test =~ $regex ]] && echo ok : "$test"
done
```

output:

```
34
{567}
{12,13,14,30,101,23}
ok : 34
ok : {567}
ok : {12,13,14,30,101,23}
```

Comment: there is something wrong, becuse it also passes for example `{12,13,14,30,101,23` or `12,13,14,30,101,23}` or `12,13,14,30,101,23`

Comment: @Chris, it's better?